# DotNet CLI build fails for VS .NET Core project when run from TFS 2015 build agent

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

**Problem**

The command `dotnet build ...` fails when run from TFS 2015 build agent with the following errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe compile-csc @(path to dotnet-compile.rsp) returned Exit Code 1

---

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Create an ASP.NET Core 1.0 web application with Visual Studio 2015 (Tools Preview 2).
2. Commit solution to TFS 2015 team project.
3. Configure a TFS 2015 Windows build agent running as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` (the default).
4. Trigger a build using the MSBuild or VSBuild task to build the solution.
5. Build fails with the errors above.

---

**Environment**

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2
- Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 - SDK Preview 2 (x64)
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2
- `dotnet --version`: 1.0.0-preview2-003121
- TFS Build Agent Version: 14.95.25122.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio needs to be launched once on the machine running the build agent using the service account assigned to the build agent.

For example, to launch Visual Studio as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`:

```
psexec -i -u "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

(PsExec can be downloaded [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx).)

The login to Visual Studio Online can be skipped.

After Visual Studio launches, the TFS build will succeed.

---

**Edit 1**

After further investigation, it appears you also need to create a new **.NET Core Web Application** project (`File -> New -> Project...`) and build it, once Visual Studio starts.